# Laravel 5 Carbon Format

Tags: php, laravel, parsing, format, php-carbon

Edit: Thanks to Mr. Davidson's comment I changed my query to this:

```
$query->where(DB::raw('MONTH(date)'), '=', Carbon::parse($month)->format('m'));
```

OP:

In my expenses overview I have a dropdown where I can select a month which then queries only the results for that particular month, like so:

```
$query->where('date', 'LIKE', '%' . Carbon::parse($month)->format('m') . '%');
```

Before, my query was like this:

```
$query->where('date', 'LIKE', '%2015-' . Carbon::parse($month)->format('m') . '%');
```

In my database I have a datetime field, so the above works, but ofcourse it only shows results from 2015. I am trying to figure out how to use the first query to show results from 2016 also.

Comment: Why not add a dropdown to select the year as well defaulting to the current year? Also are you actually storing the date as a string? There are better ways for doing a date query than using a LIKE query if you are storing them in a proper format.

Comment: Thanks, I should look into that, I am using LIKE because I am still a n00b ;) Storing as datetime btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `whereRaw` or `LIKE`, you can use the `whereMonth` method:

```
$query->whereMonth('date', '=', Carbon::parse($month)->format('m'));
```

Because it's much easier to read. The method is not documented in the [Laravel Query Builder Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries), but you can check out the [Query Builder API](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereMonth) to see the method signature, as well as to check out what other methods are available for use when building queries (since there are quite a few that are not being described in the official documentation).

Comment: Just an FYI the resulted SQL from using this would be something like `select * from "test" where strftime('%m', "date") = ?"` you can chain it with `whereYear` to get something like `select * from "test" where strftime('%m', "date") = ? and strftime('%Y', "date") = ?"` which should meet your needs.

Comment: @MarkDavidson Actually `whereMonth` uses the MySQL [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function. So that would translate to `where MONTH(date) = ?`.